# SQL string driving me crazy

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a SQL query generated in MS Access VBE that is working... just not exactly as it should.

The query looks like this:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM qryPOExamDetail
WHERE [Job Number]= '*' AND [LookUp] = '100M' OR [LookUp] = '120M' OR [LookUp] = '130M' OR [LookUp] = '140M' OR [LookUp] = '150M'
```

This returns all of the records except `'100M'`. What am I doing wrong?  I've played around all afternoon with parenthesis with no luck.

I just changed some parameters and it works like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM qryPOExamDetail WHERE [Job Number]= 'C18TN02001' AND ([LookUp] = '100M' OR [LookUp] = '120M' OR [LookUp] = '130M' OR [LookUp] = '140M' OR [LookUp] = '150M')
```

Two other changes:

```sql
SELECT * FROM qryPOExamDetail WHERE [Job Number]= 'C18TN02001' AND [LookUp] IN ('100M','120M')
```

The above works, however this doesn't:

```sql
SELECT * FROM qryPOExamDetail WHERE [Job Number]= '*' AND [LookUp] IN ('100M','120M')
```

Answer (score 2):

For readability, I'd be inclined to use the [`in`](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/in-operator-d5a10cdc-cdb2-4854-be22-7abdeb5a3236) operator as Gordon Linoff has correctly suggested, but to offer a more concise alternative, you could also use the [`like`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/like-operator-b2f7ef03-9085-4ffb-9829-eef18358e931) operator in the following manner:

```sql
select * from qryPOExamDetail where [Job Number]= "*" and [LookUp] like "1[02345]0M"
```

---

Also note that:

```sql
[Job Number]= "*"
```

Is matching a `Job Number` **exactly equal to** `*`, and is **not** using the asterisk as a wildcard operator to match **all** possible values of `Job Number`.

To match all values, use the [`like`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/like-operator-b2f7ef03-9085-4ffb-9829-eef18358e931) operator for this field as well, e.g.:

```sql
[Job Number] like "*"
```

---

The reason that your original query returned everything **except** where `LookUp = "100M"` is due to [operator precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/operator-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

The `and` operator has precedence over the `or` operator, meaning that your original query...

```sql
SELECT *
FROM qryPOExamDetail
WHERE 
    [Job Number]= '*' AND [LookUp] = '100M' 
    OR [LookUp] = '120M' 
    OR [LookUp] = '130M' 
    OR [LookUp] = '140M'
    OR [LookUp] = '150M'
```

...reads:

*"Select everything from the `qryPOExamDetail` table where `Job Number` equals `*` and `LookUp` equals `'100M'`, or where `LookUp` equals `'120M'`, or where `LookUp` equals `'130M'` ..."*

Here, the operator precedence is loosely translated into the punctuation in the above sentence.

Therefore, because there is evidently no record for which the `Job Number` value equals `*` and the `LookUp` value equals `'100M'`, no record was returned for this combination of criteria.

Comment: Thank you both for taking the time to comment.  Lee the problem is the LookUp values total about 60 and can be in any combination.  I've solved that issue...it is the  [ Job Number] = '*' that is giving me problems.  I can turn the LookUp filters off and it exports just fine...on top of all of this is I'm not the sharpest tool in the shed.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean query (not "string") and that the logic you intend is:

```
SELECT *
FROM qryPOExamDetail
WHERE [Job Number]= '*' AND
      [LookUp] IN ('100M', '120M', '130M', '140M', '150M');
```

You could also fix the logic using parentheses, but `IN` is the better method.

You might also want to change the quotes:

```
WHERE [Job Number] = "*" AND
      [LookUp] IN ("100M", "120M", "130M", "140M", "150M")
```

MS Access uses double quotes to delimit strings, rather than single quotes.